# Unable to display highcharts graphs with setextremes

Tags: flask, highcharts

I am collecting info from weather sensors(every 5 mins) and through the days and months, the amount of records is huge and render the chart takes for ever....It is working ,but the delay is too high... So instead of displaying all the values at once, I want to make the graph based on range of dates selected, and get data accordingly.

I am using python , sqlite3 and Flask and trying to copy this example from Highcharts

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/lazy-loading/

In the example they use php , which here is the code

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/samples/data/from-sql.php

This is my setextreme function in the html page

```
function setExtremes(e)
// detect zoom button
{
if(typeof(e.rangeSelectorButton)!== 'undefined')
{
    if (e.rangeSelectorButton.type=='all')
    {
        var chart = Highcharts.charts[0];
        chart.showLoading('Loading data from server...');
        $.getJSON('http://192.168.0.74:5000/rango?start=' + Math.round(e.min) +'&end=' + Math.round(e.max) + '&callback=?', function (data) {



    // Arrange data

    alert('I am in')        
    for (i = 0; i< data.length; i++)
    {
        processed_json_temperatura.push(data[i][0], data[i][1]);
        processed_json_presion.push(data[i][0], data[i][2]);
        processed_json_humedad.push(data[i][0], data[i][3]);
        processed_json_lluvia.push(data[i][0], data[i][4]);
        processed_json_horas_frio.push(data[i][0], data[i][5]);
    }

    temperatura_matriz =  listToMatrix( processed_json_temperatura,2);
    presion_matriz = listToMatrix( processed_json_presion,2);
    humedad_matriz = listToMatrix( processed_json_humedad,2);
    lluvia_matriz = listToMatrix( processed_json_lluvia,2);
    horas_frio_matriz = listToMatrix(processed_json_horas_frio,2);

//update graphs with new values

    chart.series[0].setData(temperatura_matriz);
    chart.series[1].setData(presion_matriz);
    chart.series[2].setData(humedad_matriz);
    chart.series[3].setData(lluvia_matriz);
    chart.series[4].setData(horas_frio_matriz);
    chart.hideLoading();
        });
    }
}
}
```

On server side, this is my python code with flask

```
@app.route("/rango")
def rango():
start=request.args.get('start')
end=request.args.get('end')
range = int(end)/1000 - int(start)/1000


# find the right table
# two days range loads minute data
if (range < 2 * 24 * 3600 * 1000):

connection = sqlite3.connect("/var/www/nueva_estacion.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("select (julianday(timestamp)-2440587.5)*86400000, round(temp1,2) as temp1, presion, round(humedad,2) as humedad, lluvia,aux1 from raw_all_sensors where datetime(timestamp) >=datetime('now', '-6 Day')")
results = cursor.fetchall()
print json.dumps(results)
return json.dumps(results)
```

When I click the zoom button(on highstock actually) I do see the message " Loading data from Server ..." but never shows the new graphs and never get "I am in" console message..

When monitoring the messaging on server side, I do get

192.168.0.122 - - [22/May/2019 19:47:22] "GET /rango?start=1558050049000&end=1558551372000&callback=jQuery18307335687220269529_1558565228146&_=1558565238543 HTTP/1.1" 200 -

where is clear start date, end date and then I do not understand the callback and the numbers that follow.

Just in case, this is the info coming from server
[1558546562999.989, 17.82, 1021, 76.15, 0, 1]

Can anyone bring some light here?

Comment: Hi @Martin bolino, Please check if data in the `setData` methods is in the format required by Highcharts. This array: `[1558546562999.989, 17.82, 1021, 76.15, 0, 1]` is a data for `candlestick` series: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.candlestick.data

Comment: this is how i am passing the info from server and is [timestamp, temperature, pressure, humidity, rain , # cold hours ] , and this is why I have the push statements and list to matrix , at the end to have [timestamp,value] for each metric. I know the format is ok, because the graph are working.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It seems that your callback function is nor fired. Maybe you should try to use more generic `$.ajax` to be able to catch the error?

Comment: Agree, the issue should be in the callback and not sure why I am getting this callback=jQuery18307335687220269529_1558565228146&_=1558565238543. BTW can you provide more details about how to use ajax in my example?

Comment: Unfortunately I can only help you with the JS code. Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3qn0916y/

Comment: With your help , is getting better, thank you . now I can see the code executing with alert messages within the call back function, but still graphs are not updated. not sure how to debug highcharts...

Comment: Hi @Martin bolino, Please try to set data only for one series, for example `series[0]` with `temperatura_matriz` values. If the data still will not update, please log the `temperatura_matriz` variable and provide me with the result.